# ERROR: Could not find method android() for arguments

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am facing a problem, when i sync my project this gradle error occurs :(

> **ERROR:** Could not find method android() for arguments [build_4igxve2xutpcfkae0ab7hnkia$_run_closure1@353dd2ed] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>   Open File

**This is my Build.gradle(project: name)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**This is my build.gradle(Module:App)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.instagram"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
//androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner28.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing this line from the top of your module's `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: i added this and not another error occurs .....                                                    `ERROR: ASCII
Open File`